# Get percentage value out of bracket at end of line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I got a string like

```
Just a text (12%)
```

Now I want to get the percentage value and remove the bracket. So far I got this regEx:

```
$result = array();
$content = preg_replace_callback('~\(([^)]*)\)~', function ($m) use (&$result) {
    $percentage = $m[1]/100;
    return '';
}, $content);
echo trim($content)."|".$percentage;
```

This should give me the output `Just a text|0.12`. The current regEx doesn't drop the %-character.

**Update**

And I need to check if the percentage-value is a correct integer - as sometimes there are

```
text (10-15%)
```

In this case, nothing should happen at all. The string keeps as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `$percentage` var as a reference to a closure so that you can use it later.

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('~\(([^)]*)\)~', function ($m) use (&$result, &$percentage) {
    $percentage = $m[1]/100;
    return '';
}, $content );
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `%` in your regex:

```
$result = array();
$content = preg_replace_callback('~\((\d+)%\)~', function ($m) use (&$result) {
//                                 here __^
    $percentage = $m[1]/100;
    return "|".$percentage;
}, $content);
echo trim($content);
```

Comment: I don't get `$percentage` outside of the function for output.

Comment: And I need to check for a correct percentage value. See updated post.

Comment: @user3848987: You should retrun the percentage in the call-back. See my edit.

Comment: @user3848987: for the second part of the question, change `[^)]` to `\d`